# How to call a function from an object got from generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm relatively new to C# so please bear with me.

I don't know how to perform this operation more efficiently.

```
public static void Foo<T>(LinkedList<T> list)
{
    foreach (Object o in list)
    {
        if (typeof(o) == typeof(MyClass1))
            (MyClass1)o.DoSomething();
        else if (typeof(o) == typeof(MyClass2))
            (MyClass2)o.DoSomething();

        ...
      }
  }
```

I would like to do something like this, or something more efficient than what I am doing now. by efficient I mean that program will run faster.

```
public static void Foo<T>(LinkedList<T> list)
{
    foreach (Object o in list)
    {
        o.DoSomething();
      }
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do the items need to be called in the same order? Have you seen `OfType`?

Comment: btw `typeof` is a compile time thing. You need to check for `null` then use `o.GetType()`

Comment: If `T` is unconstrained, then there isn't anything you can call on it -- it could be literally any type at all.  Perhaps you want something like `where T : IMyInterface`, in which case you ensure that the list can only contain objects that implement `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a polymorphic behavior.

```
abstract class Base // could also simply be interface, such as ICanDoSomething
{
     public abstract void DoSomething();
}

class MyClass1 : Base
{
    public override void DoSomething() { /* implement */ }
}
```

In this case, you can define your method to constraint `T` to `Base`, and then you are allowed to use the method *defined* against `Base` but *implemented* by each derived class.

```
public static void Foo<T>(LinkedList<T> list) where T : Base // or T : ICanDoSomething
{    
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
         item.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

You generally do not want to resort to type checking inside methods, as you seem to have already realized. It's not particularly about *efficiency* as it is about good programming practice. Each time you add a new class, you have to come back to the method and add yet another check, which violates all kinds of *solid* programming practices.

Answer (score 2):

Implement some interface for your types

```
public interface IMyType
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class MyType1 : IMyType
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}

public class MyType2 : IMyType
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

and use like

```
public static void Foo<T>(LinkedList<T> list) where T: IMyType
{
    foreach (T o in list)
    {
        o.DoSomething();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public static void Foo<T>(LinkedList<T> list) where T : IDoSomething
{
    foreach (T o in list)
    {
        o.DoSomething();
    }
}
```